# How Postgresql is impacted by low storage space?

Tags: database, postgresql, azure-sql-database, postgresql-11

I'm currently in the process of migrating some PostgreSQL 11 databases to Azure, in the process of configuring the database storage I end up in doubt about how PostgreSQL manager the disk space.

Taking into consideration the storage space, how much free space should I leave on my database? I want to reduce the cost without having substantial performance hits by only having what a need. Expanding the storage space when needed is not a problem.

How and at what level having low free space can affect my performance?

For context, I have databases with sizes between 70GB and 90GB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could ref the document: [Pricing tiers in Azure Database for PostgreSQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/postgresql/concepts-pricing-tiers):
[image]

You can add additional storage capacity during and after the creation of the server, and allow the system to grow storage automatically based on the storage consumption of your workload. **Storage can only be scaled up, not down.**

This document can help you know more about the [Azure PostgreSQL storage management](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/postgresql/concepts-pricing-tiers#reaching-the-storage-limit).

As you said, your database size is 70GB and 90GB. the **Basic** price tier is suitable. Per my experience about Azure SQL database, 75% or 80% is the alert metric usually. You could first provision the storage not less than 90GB*120%=108GB.

HTH.

Answer (score 1):

If the provisioned storage limit of the databases is equal or less than 10 GB, then create and [alert](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/postgresql/howto-alert-on-metric) when the data has consumed 80%.

If the provisioned storage limit of the databases is equal or less than 100 GB, then create and alert when the data has consumed 90%. For everything else create an alert when space has been consumed on 95%.

If your server is reaching provisioned storage limits, it will soon be out of space and set to read-only.

Monitor your usage and you can also provision for more storage to continue using the server without deleting any files, logs, and more.

A common issue when provisioning low storage capacity is the IOPS. The lower the storage capacity the less IOPS it can handle. If your application requires high IOPs, or you see queries having poor performance and waiting for IO, then it is recommended that you create an Azure Database for PostgreSQL server with a higher storage size to get more IOPs so that your application performance is not impacted by storage throttling.